# How to use JSQMessages and XMPP framework?

Tags: ios, xmpp, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

For developing iOS instant messaging apps, I did some research and found that there are `JSQMessages` for the UI build and `XMPP framework` for the core. Am I right? My questions are that what's the relationship between them? Should I use one of them for my iOS IM app or both?

Comment: you can use `xmpp framework` for instant messaging. you do not need to use JSMessages for UI. you can use your UI for the chatting screen

Comment: @GauravParmar, I see. So if I don't want to write UI, I can use `JSQMessages` for UI too, right?

Comment: yes you can use.... But creating your own design is more effective.